# N-Gram with ArrayList

Tags: java, n-gram, collocation

I am undergoing a project where I am analysing 'ngrams'.  I have a method in my program that creates bigrams and trigrams.  However, they only get the consecutive adjacent words together where I want it to get all combinations of words...

For example,

```
 Original String - "chilli, start, day, suffer, raynaud, check, raynaudsuk, great, tip, loveyourglov, ram"
 Bigram - "chilli start, start day, day suffer, suffer raynaud, raynaud check, check raynaudsuk, raynaudsuk great, great tip, tip loveyourglov, loveyourglov ram"
```

But I want it to get a combination of ALL the words in the String. For example

```
Expected Bigram - "chilli start,1, chilli day,2, chilli suffer,3, chilli raynaud,4, chilli check,5, chilli raynaudsuk,6, chilli great,7, chilli tip,8, chilli loveyourglov,9, chilli ram,10, start day,1, etc..."
```

How can I amend my method to produce a bigram like this?

```
public ArrayList<String> bigramList;
ArrayList<String> fullBagOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();


public void bigramCreator(){
    int i = 0;
    bigramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String bi : fullBagOfWords){
        int n = 2;
        if (i <= fullBagOfWords.size() - n) {
            String bigram = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
            bigram += fullBagOfWords.get(i + j) + " ";
            bigram += fullBagOfWords.get(i + n - 1);
            bigramList.add(bigram);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for any help given.

Comment: Aren't you missing some braces for the nested loop? The loop will execute only `bigram += fullBagOfWords.get(i + j) + " ";`

Comment: @radoh - it works fine for the top example, thats what I get but I want to expand my method to get a combination of ALL the words

Comment: Why is there a zero distance in `start day, 0,`, shouldn't it be `1`?

Comment: @radoh - aw yeah sorry thats a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, it should be very simple

```
for (int i = 0; i < fullBagOfWords.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < fullBagOfWords.size(); j++) {
        bigramList.add(fullBagOfWords.get(i) + " " + fullBagOfWords.get(j) + ", " + (j - i));
    }
}
```

Comment: this does work a bit the way I want it, but is there anyway to add the distance between each word ?

Comment: @JohnLewis Add distance how/where excatly? Can you clarify it in your original question?

Comment: iv changed my question, i forgot to originally post it sorry

Comment: @JohnLewis I've fixed my answer